# Defining sw identifiers in <supports-screens> attribute in the manifest

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have several drawable folders in my app. Such as drawable-sw600dp-hdpi and drawable-sw480dp-mdpi, etc.  How can I define them in  attribute in the manifest file? In the developer documentation I can only see that I have to set true to large, xlarge, small, etc. But that's not exactly what I need. Because I don't want 10 inch tablets to download my app, but only 7 inch tablets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"`. Do something like this-

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="4"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

For more help [check this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: How can I define that in google play publisher page if I want to have multiple apk based on screen sizes?